# C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] en un simple contador

Tags: c

Se trata de un algoritmo que lea n frases, y despues cuente cuantas palabras hay en cada frase, pero a la hora que quiero hacer el conteo de espacios en la frase me da ese error del titulo. 
El codigo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Max 5

int main()
{
     char oracion[100];
     char oraciones [Max][20];
     int i,h,NdO,k,j,contPalabras=1;

     printf("¿Cuantas oraciones desea ordenar? ");
     scanf ("%d",&NdO);
     fflush(stdin);
     for(k=0;k<NdO;k++) //Contador oraciones
     { 
     printf("Ingrese la oracion numero %d\n", k+1 );
     gets (oraciones [k]);
     }


     for(h=0;h<strlen(oraciones[h]);h++)
         if (oraciones[h] == ' ' && h > 0 && oraciones[h - 1] != ' ')
               contPalabras++;

               }
```

Answer (score 3):

**No** lo indicas, pero tu error se encuentra aquí:

```
  ...
  char oraciones[Max][20];
  ...
  if( oraciones[h] == ' ' && h > 0 && oraciones[h - 1] != ' ' ) // <- AQUÍ
```

El error es muy sencillo: tu variable `oraciones` es una **formación de formaciones de caracteres**; es decir, `oraciones[x]` es una **formación de caracteres**.

Y los tipos `tipo[X]` *decaen*, automáticamente, al tipo `tipo *`. Es decir, en realidad, eso **es un puntero**. Es como si hubieras declarado `char *oraciones[20]`.

Fíjate que digo `es como si`. En las formaciones, el compilador realmente **si** reserva el espacio indicado, pero el lenguaje C **no puede** tratar con *espacios* de memoria. Únicamente sabe tratar con *punteros*. Y eso es lo que el compilador hace: **te hace el favor de devolverte un puntero** que, valga la redundancia, *apunta* al espacio de memoria que ha sido reservada.

Con esto en mente, tu error es fácil de entender: **no puedes comparar un puntero con un número**; porque, por otra parte, `' '` es **un número**: el código ASCII del caracter *espacio*.

¿ La solución ? Pues *no mezclar peras con manzanas:*

```
for( int linea = 0; linea < Max; ++linea )
    for( size_t letra = 0; letra < strlen( oraciones[linea] ); ++letra )
      if( oraciones[linea][letra] == ' ' && letra > 0 && oraciones[linea][letra - 1] != ' ' )
      contPalabras++;
```

Answer (score 2):

El error que recibes es claro, autoexplicativo y conciso:

> C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, lo traduzco:

> C++ prohíbe la comparación entre puntero y entero

Para empezar, sorprende que recibas un error etiquetado como C++ en un código claramente C y que has etiquetado como C en el sitio; revisa los parámetros de tu compilador.

Para acabar, el error es sobre comparaciones, en tu código las únicas comparaciones explícitas están en esta instrucción:

```
oraciones[h] == ' ' && h > 0 && oraciones[h - 1] != ' '
```

El tipo de `operaciones` es `char[5][20]`, una formación bidimensional de caracteres. Eliminando una dimensión (accediendo a una de las colecciones con el operador de indexado `[]`) aún queda la otra; en otras palabras el tipo `operaciones[índice]` es `char*` (puntero a carácter) y lo estás comparando contra `' '` (espacio en blanco); el cuál se promociona a entero en la comparación dando lugar al error que encuentras.

Por suerte, el problema es muy fácil de solucionar:

```
*oraciones[h] == ' ' && h > 0 && *oraciones[h - 1] != ' '
```